# jQuery light-box and Links won't work in Layout - CSS Issue?

Tags: jquery

Links and Lightbox images won't work on this page for some reason:

http://avisuals.web.fc2.com/pricing.html

Links will work outside the content box in the footer area at the bottom but won't work inside the box???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `z-index: -1;` from `#content2` definition in your `css` file.

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have known that I was so busy working on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a negative `z-index` applied to the `#content2` box.

Comment: That's it! Why didn't I think of that!? Thank you so much! That was quick.